# Qt installer framework does not set properties to installer/executable

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I have created a simple installer via QtIF. In config file I specified all required tags, including Version, Product Name and Product Version. On Properties->Details page there all properties are empty. I expected that it will be filled by framework automatically.

[image: file_details]

Should QtIF fill file-details?

If no, can I write these properties by some other tool?

Or, at least can end-user get file-version specified in config.xml, for bug tracking purposes?